# TypeError at /wiki/HTML

Tags: python, django, templates

When I try to load my title.html template this TypeError occurs. My logic is simple:
If an entry is requested that does not exist, the user should be presented with an error page indicating that their requested page was not found.
If the entry does exist, the user should be presented with a page that displays the content of the entry. The title of the page should include the name of the entry.

My urlpatterns (inside encyclopedia/urls.py):

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("wiki/", views.title, name="title"),]
```

My views (inside encyclopedia/views.py):

```
def title(request, title_name):
return render(request, "encyclopedia/title.html",{
    "entry": util.get_entry(title_name),
    "title": util.get_page_name(title_name)
})
```

And of course the util.py as follows:

```
def get_entry(title):

try:
    f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
    return f.read().decode("utf-8")
except FileNotFoundError:
    return None
def get_page_name(title):
try:
    name = os.path.basename(f'entries/{title}')
    return name
except TypeError:
    return None
```

For more info regarding the title.html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}

<p>{{ title }}</p>

{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
<p> {{ entry }}</p>
{% endblock body %}
```

Since I get a **TypeError** *at /wiki/HTML title() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'* my guess is that the template I wrote doesn't do the job?

Comment: Note: Inside encyclopedia/entries there are .md files such as 'HTML','Django' etc. present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your path to something like this so this will work

```
path("wiki/<str:title_name>/", views.title, name="title")
```